# Violation - event handler took <N> ms slows app significantly

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mISIR.jpg

I get tons of such errors in a (pretty big) react app scaffolded with cra, when scrolling, when loading the page initially, when receiveing payloads from web sockets, some are blocking the app for as much as 15000ms, what could be causing this?

I just don't have any clue how to debug this, the chrome profiler seems like a start, but I would like any insight that could ease my suffering, cause right now I am about 15 hours deep into debugging.

Comment: The question isn't answerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve) or it least a trace file from profiler. You probably render a lot of stuff in those tasks so try to render just the general UI first, yield via requestAnimationFrame, render the visible part of the data, yield and render the rest in chunks repetitively.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you for your input, I am not sure what can I provide since this is quite a big app, I was thinking maybe there is an obvious mistake in cases like these that someone can point me to. Anyway thanks again, I will try to figure it on my own now.